# Swift - Objective C - "Controller" Does not conform to Protocol JBBarChartViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'am trying to use JawBone/JBChartView Charts in a Swift App
In my ViewController I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , JBBarChartViewDelegate {
...
}
```

I have implemented the method to conform the protocol:

```
override func heightForBarViewAtIndex (bc: JBBarChartView , index: Int) -> Double{
    //return 1;
}
```

The JBarChartViewDelegate is a ObjectiveC Class so the original method to implement is:

```
- (CGFloat)barChartView:(JBBarChartView *)barChartView heightForBarViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

I can not compile the code I get a "ViewController Does not conform to Protocol JBBarChartViewDelegate"

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the override from in front of the fund.

Comment: No, that is not the problem

Comment: Have you implemented all non optional methods of the protocol?
Also check the bridging header for the exact signature of the protocol methods.

Comment: Sure, there is just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the problem was the Int parameter, it has to be Uint. So the final method to implement is:

```
func barChartView(barChartView: JBBarChartView!, heightForBarViewAtIndex index: UInt) -> CGFloat{
    return 0.0
}
```

Thsnks to you all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue may be that you are using the wrong types. Your return value seems to be returning a `Double` in your override function when the declaration specifies a `CGFloat`. As well, I believe the function should start out with the same words that the declared method does. You wrote `heightForBarViewAtIndex(` when I believe it would translate to what it looks like below.

Try this:

```
override func barChartView(barChartView: JBBarChartView, heightForBarViewAtIndex index: UInt) -> CGFloat { 
    return 0.0 
}
```

Comment: I have change a bit your code and not working, func barChartView(barChartView : JBBarChartView!, heightForBarViewAtIndex index: Int) -> CGFloat{
       return 0.0
    }